# aliyun cli SDK Error on product Container Registry (CR)

Tags: alibaba-cloud

Hello I'm using **aliyun** CLI Version **3.0.15**

and configure the right credentials to it

```
 ./aliyun --version
Alibaba Cloud Command Line Interface Version 3.0.15
```

When i query **GetRegion** or any other defined API related to **Container Registry (CR)** I got the SDK Error

**Usage one**

```
$ ./aliyun cr  GetRegion
ERROR: SDK.ServerError
ErrorCode: ServiceUnavailable
Recommend: https://error-center.aliyun.com/status/search?Keyword=ServiceUnavailable&source=PopGw
RequestId: 2FBF6A60-D3F1-46A2-8985-919B44032B45
Message: The request has failed due to a temporary failure of the server.
```

**Usage Two**

```
$ ./aliyun cr GET /regions
ERROR: SDK.ServerError
ErrorCode: ServiceUnavailable
Recommend: https://error-center.aliyun.com/status/search?Keyword=ServiceUnavailable&source=PopGw
RequestId: 64E93F6F-94FE-45B8-9550-9E2B77EFD623
Message: The request has failed due to a temporary failure of the server.
```

I checked the API it's correct

```
./aliyun cr --help
```

What wrong i'm doing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macOS Mojave 10.14.4, I was able to reproduce your issue (also using aliyun cli version 3.0.15). The issue seems to be (as @wanghq mentioned) that the team has made an update to the aliyuncli tool that hasn't made it into the binary yet. I was able to fix the issue by compiling from source:

```
export GOPATH=/Users/xiaomei/Downloads
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/aliyuncd $GOPATH/src/github.com/aliyun
cd $GOPATH
git clone http://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-cli.git
git clone http://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-openapi-meta.git
cd aliyun-cli/
make install
sudo cp out/aliyun /usr/local/bin/.
```

Of course your GOPATH should be replaced with something else (/Users/xiaomei being my own home directory!).

I added the last line to make sure aliyun gets moved to /usr/local/bin, because that's where I prefer to keep it. You could just run it from the build directory if you prefer.

The command `aliyun cr GetRegionList` works fine after I build from source.

Comment: Thanks Jermey for Joining the stackoverflow and providing the resolution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising the issue. The team just updated the meta config. If you install the latest aliyun cli from [github](https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-cli) ("Compile source code"), everything should work properly.

```
aliyun cr GetRegion
{
    "data": {
        "regions": [
            {
                "localName": "华东1（杭州）",
                "domains": [
                    {
                        "domain": "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com",
                        "network": "public"
                    },
                    {
                        "domain": "registry-internal.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com",
                        "network": "internal"
                    },
                    {
                        "domain": "registry-vpc.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com",
                        "network": "vpc"
                    }
                ],
                "regionId": "cn-hangzhou"
            },
```